# Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State. - Multiple Hubs in SignalR

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I'm attempting to get to grips with SignalR, to do so I'm trying to extend the functionality of the simple chat room tutorial that Microsoft provide in their documentation.

I'm now trying to add a second hub, which will allow the user to do send in integers and receive the value multiplied by 10. The hub itself is almost identical to the normal ChatHub, except with an extra step that checks the input is a number and does the multiplication.

ChatHub

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string group,string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.Group(group).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }

        public async Task AddToGroup(string groupName)
        {
            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);

            await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("Send", $"{Context.ConnectionId} has joined the group {groupName}.");
        }
    }
```

CalcHub

```
public class CalcHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string group, string user, string message)
        {
            var value = MultiplyByTen(message);

            await Clients.Group(group).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, value);
        }

        public async Task AddToGroup(string groupName)
        {
            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);

            await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("Send", $"{Context.ConnectionId} has joined the group {groupName}.");
        }

        public string MultiplyByTen(string input)
        {
            bool isANumber = Int32.TryParse(input, out int value);

            if (isANumber)
            {
                return (value * 10).ToString();
            }

            return "Not a number";
        }
    }
```

I have Javascript set up for my front-end, which works perfectly fine when I try to connect to the ChatHub and send messages, however when I attempt to use the connection to CalcHub, I get the `Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State` error message.

Here is how the two connections are established.

```
var calcConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("https://localhost:44309/calcHub").build();
var chatConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("https://localhost:44308/chatHub").build();
var activeConnection;

setConnection();

$("#hubSelector").on("change",
    function(data) {
        setConnection();
    });
```

I have a simple `select` element that will swap the connection based on its value. SetConnection is the method that controls this, which is used at DOM ready to set the initial connection.

Both of the hubs are registered in my startup class too.

```
            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
                routes.MapHub<CalcHub>("/calcHub");
            });
```

If I navigate to the two addresses of the hubs `https://localhost:44309/calcHub` and `https://localhost:44309/chatHub`, I can also see that they are valid addresses as I get the `Connection ID required` message.

Why is my `calcHub` not working?

Site.js

```
// Please see documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification
// for details on configuring this project to bundle and minify static web assets.

// Write your JavaScript code.

$(function() {
    var calcConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("https://localhost:44309/calcHub").build();
    var chatConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("https://localhost:44308/chatHub").build();
    var activeConnection;

    //setConnection();

    //$("#hubSelector").on("change",
    //    function(data) {
    //        setConnection();
    //    });




    activeConnection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
        var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
        var encodedMsg = user + " says " + msg;
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.textContent = encodedMsg;
        document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
    });

    activeConnection.start().catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });



    $("#addgroup").on("click", function () {
        var group = document.getElementById("group").value;
        activeConnection.invoke("AddToGroup", group).catch(function (err) {
            return console.error(err.toString());
        });
        $("#group-list").append("<p>" + group + "</p>");
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#sendButton").on("click", function () {
        var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
        var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
        var group = document.getElementById("group").value;
        activeConnection.invoke("SendMessage", group, user, message).catch(function (err) {
            return console.error(err.toString());
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    function setConnection() {
        var selectValue = $("#hubSelector").val();

        if (selectValue === "chat") {
            $("#activeHub").html("<span>Active Hub: Chat</span>");
            activeConnection = chatConnection;
        }

        if (selectValue === "calc") {
            $("#activeHub").html("<span>Active Hub: Calc</span>");
            activeConnection = calcConnection;
        }

        console.log(activeConnection);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi. Can you share the entire codebase on Github or similar?
Or can you share the javascript for the page?

Comment: @Kiksen Hi, I've added the whole site.js file to the post.